# Exception Value: libFreeCADApp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: django, docker, freecad

I can't figure out how to use external library as python module in production. Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

I am importing [FreeCAD](https://wiki.freecadweb.org/Embedding_FreeCAD) as python module in my django app as follow.

**views.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('freecad/lib')
import FreeCAD
import Part
```

And Freecad bin and library files reside at root directory where manage.py file is as shown below.

[image: ![image](/uploads/9a84bf7561f021e499ad84ba03764810/image.png)]

Everything works fine on my local sever. I can import FreeCad and do data processing on CAD files.
But things start to break when I deploy app on google cloud engine. After deployment it threw this error.

`Exception Value:  libFreeCADApp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I also built docker image of this application to make sure consistent dependencies. But same result local sever finds Freecad library and runs fine, but docker throws this error.
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FreeCAD'`.

**Docker file content**

```
# Base Image
FROM python:3.8.5
# set default environment variables # Dont wory about this
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 

# create and set working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Add current directory code to working directory
ADD . /app/

# Pass requirements to Docker

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt



# set project environment variables
# grab these via Python's os.environ
# these are 100% optional here
ENV PORT=8888

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        tzdata \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-pip \
        python3-dev \
        python3-venv \
        git \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# install environment dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip3 install pipenv
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt

# Install project dependencies
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev

EXPOSE 8888
CMD gunicorn mod_project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.3.1
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
Django==3.1.4
django-storages==1.10.1
google-api-core==1.23.0
google-auth==1.23.0
google-cloud-core==1.4.4
google-cloud-storage==1.33.0
google-crc32c==1.0.0
google-resumable-media==1.1.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
kiwisolver==1.3.1
matplotlib==3.3.3
numpy==1.19.4
numpy-stl==2.13.0
Pillow==8.0.1
protobuf==3.14.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
PyMySQL==0.10.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-utils==2.4.0
pytz==2020.4
requests==2.25.0
rsa==4.6
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
stripe==2.55.1
urllib3==1.26.2
```

Comment: Please post your `Dockerfile` contents

Comment: Hi Eyal, Added Docker File Content.

Comment: What are the contents of `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Added contents of requirements.txt. Just to be on same page, it doesn't have freecad module. Freecad library is coming from .so files (dlls on windos) as shown in image.